# AWS Lambda, Snowflake connector and "module 'cryptography.hazmat.bindings._rust.openssl' has no attribute 'hashes'"

Tags: python, aws-lambda, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am creating a layer for the snowflake connector.
I downloaded amazon linux image, installed the snowflake connector in the image:
`pip install snowflake-connector-python`;

after that I uploaded the layer and lambda through SAM installation.
Lambda is still giving me this issue though

```
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py\", line 127, in import_module\n    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 1030, in _gcd_import\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 1007, in _find_and_load\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 680, in _load_unlocked\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>\", line 850, in exec_module\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/app.py\", line 2, in <module>\n    import snowflake.connector\n",
```

any ideas appreciated.

python 3.9.16

snowflake-connector-python==3.6.0
cryptography==41.0.7

amazonlinux: 2023.2.20231113.0

Comment: Update Python 3.12.1